# Yeah, but HOW MANY out-of-state plates?

Tags: idioms, grammatical-number

*He said, “I saw two men runnin’ out, they looked like middleweights /
They jumped into a white car with out-of-state plates”*

*- [Hurricane](https://www.bobdylan.com/songs/hurricane/), by Bob Dylan and Jacques Levy*

It seems like we always say "out-of-state plates" in the plural, although when all is well each car has only one license plate. Why not "an out-of-state plate"?

Comment: It is idiomatic to speak of the “plates” of a car. English is not bound to follow any logic. It does what it does and we follow. That said, at least in my life experience, most cars have two plates: front and rear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It seems like we always say "out-of-state plates" in the plural,
>   although when all is well each car has only one license plate. Why not
>   "an out-of-state plate"?

When "all is well", in a significant majority of US states, a car will have two plates, one at the front, and one at the rear.

Front and rear plates required:

> Alaska, American Samoa, California, Colorado, District of Columbia,
>   Connecticut, Guam,[30] Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Iowa, Maine, Maryland,
>   Minnesota, Missouri, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New York, North
>   Dakota, Northern Mariana Islands, Ohio, Oregon, Rhode Island, Texas,
>   Utah, Vermont, Virgin Islands, Virginia, Washington, Wisconsin

Front and rear plates required for most vehicles:

> Massachusetts, Montana, Nebraska, Nevada, South Dakota, Wyoming

Rear plates only required:

> Alabama, Arizona, Arkansas, Delaware, Florida, Georgia, Indiana,
>   Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana, Michigan, Mississippi, New Mexico, North
>   Carolina, Oklahoma, Pennsylvania, Puerto Rico, South Carolina,
>   Tennessee, West Virginia

[Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_States (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_States)

Comment: What about other English speaking countries?

Comment: @DanBron *Hurricane* isn't set in other English speaking countries.

Comment: TIL: There are places in the world where cars are not required to have both a front and a rear number plate. Never even considered that such a thing might be the case.

Comment: That's funny. It actually never occurred to me that ANY states require that, because I've always lived in the states on your last list, states requiring only a rear plate.

Comment: Although, technically, only a rear plate is *required* in Canada, every car has a front and rear plate unless something is "unusual." You wouldn't be charged or fined if you drove with only a rear plate—but you might be pulled over and questioned. I've seen dealership cars on a test drive with only a rear plate (and attached in a temporary fashion rather than screwed on). But license plates are provided by the government in pairs and you are expected to use both.

Answer (score 1):

This is because cars have two license plates:  One on the front and one on the back.  So

> *They jumped into a white car with out-of-state plates*

is correct, though usually when you refer to cars you say *the car's numberplate* rather than *the car's numberplate**s***.  But since this rhymes, *plates* must be used, as well as the fact that it is informal.

Comment: This isn’t true for many states.  See https://www.cars.com/articles/2013/10/how-many-states-require-front-license-plates/

Comment: There is already an answer stating this.  If you read it, you'll see most states *do*.  I'm answering from a majority perspective.

Comment: What about other English speaking countries?

Comment: They aren't relevant, because it's an American song

Comment: @Dan Since this answer deals in number plates and is written by a user who did English GCSEs, it arguably **is** about other English-speaking countries (than the US, that is). In any case, are you aware of any English-speaking countries that _don’t_ use two plates?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’m an American. I’m vaguely aware there’s something beyond the Atlantic, but I’m not certain of it.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - "Since this answer... is written by a user who did English GCSEs," Yes, but what grades?

Comment: 9s (A**) in America